# Yii2, jQuery : .prop('disabled', true); all field when value="x"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-basic-app

when I choose `radioList value=CANCEL`  and SAVE it to model.

After that when I click `UPDATE(actionUpdate)` I want to disabled all field

Here the inspectElement field Activity[status].

```
<input type="radio" name="Activity[status]" value="CANCEL" data-index="1">
```

[image]

my requirement is I want the jQuery check if field `Activity[status] value="CANCEL"` then disabled all field.

and here jQuery that I need to coding. but I don't know how to write statement to get `value="CANCEL"` and then execute `.prop('disabled', true);`

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs("
        // here coding for get name="Activity[status]" value="CANCEL" and then
        $('#all_field_want_to_disabled').prop('disabled', true);
    ");
?>
```

Comment: try `$('input[type="radio"][name="Activity\\[status\\]"][value="CANCEL"]').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I put this 
`<?php
$this->registerJs("
 $('input[type="radio"][name=\"Activity[status]\"][value="CANCEL"]').prop('disabled', true);
");
?>`
and get an error
`syntax error, unexpected 'radio' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'`

Comment: then I change double quotes to  single quotes

`$('input[type="radio"][name="Activity\\[status\\]"][value="CANCEL"]').prop('disabled', true);`

to 

`"$('input[type='radio'][name=\"Activity[status]\"][value='CANCEL']').prop('disabled', true);"`


get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: if you start with `'` as in `$('')` then you have to use double quotes for anything inside that, as in `$('input[type="radio"]')`

Comment: `registerJs(" $('input[type="radio"][name=\"Activity[status]\"][value="CANCEL"]').prop('disabled', true); ")` should be `registerJs(" $('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"Activity\\[status\\]\"][value=\"CANCEL\"]').prop('disabled', true); ")`

Comment: but that not working. your code is always disabled value="CANCEL" in radioList(PENNDING and CANCEL).

my requirement is I want to check if field `Activity[status]`  selected 
 `value="CANCEL"` then disabled all field in radioList(PENNDING and CANCEL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have a `radioList` like below given my `$model` name is `Activity`

```
$form->field ( $model , "status" )->radioList(['PENDING'=>'PENDING','CANCEL'=>'CANCEL']);
```

Adding the following line of code on top of the view field will disable all form fields if the selected radio input has the value `CANCEL` when the form is loaded.

```
$this->registerJs('if($("input[name=\'Activity[status]\']:checked").val()=="CANCEL"){$("input").prop("disabled", true);}',\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```